# How do i send data to a server with dojo?

Tags: ajax, dojo

I want to send two names and a number to a server by using a dojo command. I just know the dojo request command but i only want to send data and not to receive some. How can i do that with dojo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But you do this with dojo request ...

The callback functions for success or error are completely optional !

Look at this snippet - assuming you required dojo/request as "request":

```
var serverUrl = 'echo.php';
var forServer = {
    data: { 'say' : 'HELLO WORLD' },
    method: "POST"
};

request.post(serverUrl, forServer);
```

---

That means, your echo.php will receive 'say' in the POST variables with the value "HELLO WORLD" ...

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['say'];
?>
```

If you send arrays or objects to the server, you should use JSON (see the docs for dojo request ...)

Comment: There is also this nice tutorial: [dojo request](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/ajax/)